# Is adaptive streaming (live http streaming) required of iphone apps that play video?

Tags: iphone, video, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, transcoding

We are creating a video intensive app and want to be sure that adaptive streaming is required (given that we need to write an automated transcoding and segmentation system to support this).  Does anyone know if the YouTube app is using adaptive streaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) you can read:

> **Important:** iPhone and iPad apps that
>   send large amounts of audio or video
>   data over cellular networks are
>   required  to use HTTP Live Streaming.

Comment: Thanks.  We saw this documentation and wondered if that's a hard requirement because the UI guidelines, for instance, say no splash screens and many apps have splash screens. We've since decided to syndicate to YouTube and then reference those videos from within the app.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the YouTube app uses adaptive streaming. It definatly doesn't look like it does on the iPad. But it does have wifi and 3G modes but I don't think it does fully adaptive streaming.

For your app if its allowed to stream over 3G then yes you are required to make it adaptive. But if you just are making an app for wifi use then you don't.